# Why is this only inserting the first values from the array?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray

I'm attempting to insert data stored in an NSMutableArray and store it in an SQLite Database..  So far I've been only able to insert the first 5 elements of the array or insert them all into the first column of the DB. I can't figure out where it's breaking/not working.

Contents of lockInfo (NSMutableArray):

```
LOCKINFO (
    51974,
    0,
    2,
    15,
    1,
    51975,
    0,
    24,
    15,
    1,
    51976,
    0,
    20,
    15,
    1,
    51977,
    0,
    23,
    15,
    1
    )
```

All that's being inserted into the first row is:

```
51974,
    0,
    2,
    15,
    1
```

Code:

```
-(void)insertLock:(NSMutableArray *)lockInfo{
    char *error;
    NSString *databasePath = [self dataPath:@"eloqdb.sqlite3"];
    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"Could not open database");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"DB opened");
    }

    //for each element in the array, save the array index, and the contact:

     NSLog(@"count %@", lockInfo);

    NSLog(@"count %i", lockInfo.count);

    for (int i = 0; i < lockInfo.count; i++) {


        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        NSString *SQLInsert = @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO LOCK_PLAN_CHANGE (ID, FLAG, ITEM_DOOR_ID, KEY_SERIAL, TIMEZONE_ITEM_ID) "
        @"VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [SQLInsert UTF8String], -1,
                               &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:3] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:4] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        }
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
            // NSAssert1(0, @"Cannot Update Table", error);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array actually contains `lockInfo.count / 5` rows worth of data.

Change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lockInfo.count; i += 5) {
```

Then update the binds to:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:i+1] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:i+2] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:i+3] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [[lockInfo objectAtIndex:i+4] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
```

Those changes will put the correct values in the correct columns and it will add the correct number of rows.

BTW - this is a really poor data structure. You should define a class or struct with 5 properties. Then have an array of that class or struct.

Besides that main issue, you also don't make proper use of a prepared statement. You should prepare the statement just once before the loop.

Here's your code written properly with better error checking as well:

```
- (void)insertLock:(NSMutableArray *)lockInfo {
    NSString *databasePath = [self dataPath:@"eloqdb.sqlite3"];
    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Could not open database");
        return;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"DB opened");
    }

    //for each element in the array, save the array index, and the contact:

    NSLog(@"lockInfo %@", lockInfo);
    NSLog(@"count %i", lockInfo.count);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSString *SQLInsert = @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO LOCK_PLAN_CHANGE (ID, FLAG, ITEM_DOOR_ID, KEY_SERIAL, TIMEZONE_ITEM_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [SQLInsert UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < lockInfo.count; i += 5) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [lockInfo[i] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [lockInfo[i+1] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [lockInfo[i+2] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [lockInfo[i+3] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [lockInfo[i+4] UTF8String], -1, NULL);

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                // NSAssert1(0, @"Cannot Update Table", error);
            }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can't prepare: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: Great explanation - very clear.  thank you...  I will research using a better data structure..